# pass DataStruct around more efficiently (winforms)

Tags: c#, winforms

i have a DataStruct[] that gets used multiple times on a form.  It is  created from reading a CSV file.  The structure has 5 "columns", each with about 100,000 rows

in particular, i have a bunch of ChangeEvents (trackbars, textboxes, etc.), where each change event is re-making the data structure, but i feel it's slowing down the changes (they are rendering on a graph, and it's slow to react)

once i have the actual structure, i don't need to change it, i just need to work with the data.  I don't know how i can create the DataStruct[] only once, then pass that struct into the various change events without rebuilding it

the following code currently exists in all my change events (edited for brevity):

```
string[] fileArray = File.ReadAllLines(tempfile);
DataStruct[] data = new DataStruct[fileArray.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < fileArray.Length; i++)
        {
            List<string> dataList = fileArray[i].Split(',').ToList<string>();
            data[i].X = (Convert.ToSingle(dataList[0]));                                             
        }
```

my confusion is:  i have a variety of void() methods that use the structure, and it's easy to pass into those.  however i don't understand how to pass into a change event, since the handler refreshes every time the change occurs, i don't know where to call the pass.  For example:

```
private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        label282.Text = trackBar1.Value.ToString();
        chart17.Series[0].Points.Clear();
        VoltageChanger();
    }
```

how would i call this Scroll change without re-doing the struct?  VoltageChanger() uses the struct to do some stuff and make a new graph based on the trackbar value.

or...am i silly in thinking that there may be a slowdown here, and it's just the graph rendering that won't get any better?

thanks (edit: i have been reading but event handling outside of the winforms defaults is currently new to me)

Comment: is `DataStruct` a actual `class` or `struct`?

Comment: it's a struct, called with private struct DataStruct.  i inherited this with some legacy code that i had to start with

Comment: You should never have a mutable struct. Unless you have a very specific reason you should make it a `class`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you read up on variable scope [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132(v=vs.71).aspx).  For your example, you need to read the information once and have it accessible to all the methods within the class.  That is what a module-level variable will do.  In the code snippet below, notice the declaration for DataStruct is within the class definition, not within any individual method.  This makes the variable visible to that class' methods.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private DataStruct[] _data;  // <-- Module level variable

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LoadData();  
    }

    private void LoadData()
    {
        // Open file code omitted
        _data = new DataStruct[fileArray.Length];
        // Read data into file omitted
    }

    private void Method1()
    {
        // _data will be accessible here because it is a module-level variable
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, i had reached that conclusion - but i was still unsure that it wouldn't just re-call (and re-make) the struct every time.  i've read through the link and i understand a lot better now.  appreciate.